# CSS (scss) variables calculations return an error

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
$toggle-width: var(--width);
$toggle-padding: $toggle-width/10 * 1.5;
```

I am trying to make this css(scss) work, at which point I can just create variables and interpolate them onto my HTML (vue js) to create a dynamically changing elements.

```
<span :class="{'not-active': computedValue == false}"
              :style="{'--width':width_t}"
              class="toggle -round ">
```

But I keep getting an error

```
   $toggle-padding: $toggle-width/10 * 1.5;
                ^
      Undefined operation "var(--width)/10 * 1.5".
   ╷
57 │ $toggle-padding: $toggle-width/10 * 1.5;
   │                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you not just use `$toggle-width` as your var and set whatever `--width` is directly to `$toggle-width`?

Comment: I tried that, 
```
$toggle-padding: var(--width)/10 * 1.5;
```
returns the same error.

Comment: @LiadGoren, Could you try ```($toggle-width/10) * 1.5```adding paranthesis() in the first operation instead of ```$toggle-width/10 * 1.5``` ??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan
$toggle-padding: ($toggle-width/10) * 1.5;
returns the same error mate, Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself...

```
 $toggle-width: var(--width);
    $toggle-padding: calc(var(--width) / 10 * 1.5);
```

but if i wanna make any further calculations, i can't call the SCSS variables, I must use the var(--width), and preform the calculations,to further mutate it.
like so:

```
top: $toggle-padding;
left: $toggle-padding;
content: "";
width: calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) / 10 * 1.5) * 2);
height: calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) / 10 * 1.5) * 2);
```

thanks for the help anyways.